# Cannot whitelist htaccess blocked admin URL

Tags: magento2, htaccess

Trying to whitelist the blocked admin URL for the outside world from htaccess but not working.

The below code worked in Magento 1. I have added this in my `root_directory/pub/.httaccess`.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^101.11.121.111
RewriteRule ^(index.php/?)?(admin|rss|downloader) - [L,R=403]
```

**This is blocking the URL but not whitelisting to my office IP.** Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working. So the problem was that `Magento 2`'s `remote address` was always `127.0.0.1`. This is I believe because of `varnish`.

So I had to use `x forwarded for`. Firstly you may need to implement `x-forwarded-for` in `Magento 2`. Learn here: https://dev98.de/2017/01/02/how-to-add-alternative-http-headers-to-magento-2/

Then below code will work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^101.11.121.111
RewriteRule ^(index.php/?)?(admin|rss|downloader) - [L,R=403]
```